# Callisto Ratings tab navigation

Tags: winrt-xaml, callisto

I'm using Callisto to add ratings to my app. Everything works fine but the tab navigation for this control.

Any idea about how to support tab navigation for this control, like the "Store" app for example? The idea is select the control (focus) and select the rating value with left/right keys (like a slider)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please feel free to log a bug/request on http://github.com/timheuer/callisto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab navigation works but it takes more tabs to hop from one rating item to another. I recommend you to use [FocusWatcher class](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/1335#.Uk2cg0FplZQ), you will be able to figure out the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very very useful helper to test and debug the tab navigation